# Is this java code correct for the question? (Without arrays)

Tags: java

The question is:

Write a java program to accept any 20 numbers and display only those numbers which are prime.

And my code is:

```
import java.io.*;
class primenumber
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
    int i,j,n;
    int p = 0;
    for(i=1;i<=20;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        n = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        p = 0;
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            if(n%j==0)
                p++;
        }
        if(p==2)
            System.out.println(n);
    }
}
}
```

So is this correct?

Comment: Looks OK at first glance.  What happens when you run it?

Comment: It works fine. My only problem is I don't know if I should print the number right after the user enters it or at the end of the loop. In here I've printed the number right after the user inputs it.

Comment: So what do you think you'd have to change, to print it at the end of the loop?

Comment: I would need to either use arrays or just keep the prime numbers in a variable and print them later but I think this is correct either way right?

Comment: Yes, you could put them in an array.  There are other types of variable you could use too.  Maybe even a `String`, with the values separated by commas.

Comment: But is my code technically able to achieve what the question asks?

Comment: If you're not sure whether you've interpreted the question correctly, you should probably ask your teacher.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell from reading your program it is correct: it does what the assignment says and without arrays.

Depending on the requirements in your class it may be argued that input validation is missing. If I enter `-4`, you program will not print it (which may be considered correct?), but if I enter `3.14` or `apple`, it will probably crash.

There are a couple of minor stilistic issues, but when you ask about correctness, the answer is yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

To print the output after the user finished entering the numbers you need to use arrays or `List`. I wrote your function using `ArrayList` to accumulate the user input, then calculate the prime numbers and finally display the results.

On the first part I change the way the input is asked to retry the input if there was an error during parsing. This way you don't loose all the numbers previously entered.

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();  
InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);

System.out.println("Enter " + total + " numbers: ");
int total = 20;
for (int i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
    try {
        System.out.print(i + " of " + total + ": ");
        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot parse input as integer");
        i--;
    }
}
```

This is not related to your question, but I also did some changes to the way you are calculating the prime numbers to make it run faster when looping over large values.

```
List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

System.out.println("Calculating primes...");
for (int n : numbers) {
    boolean isPrime = true;
    if (n > 1) {
        for (int dividend = 2; dividend <= n / 2; dividend++) {
            if (n % dividend == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime)
            primes.add(n);
    }
}
```

Finally to print the list of prime numbers I am first sorting the list in ascending order using the Java 8 natural order comparator. This makes the output easier to read.

```
primes.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
if (primes.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("No prime numbers found");
} else {
    System.out.println("primes: " + primes);
}
```

**Sample output**

```
Enter 20 numbers: 
1 of 20: 1
2 of 20: 2
3 of 20: 3
4 of 20: 4
5 of 20: 5
6 of 20: 7
7 of 20: 9
8 of 20: 11
9 of 20: 13
10 of 20: 17
11 of 20: 
Cannot parse input as integer
11 of 20: 99999999999999
Cannot parse input as integer
11 of 20: 123456789
12 of 20: 987654321
13 of 20: 41
14 of 20: 71
15 of 20: 98
16 of 20: 1239213
17 of 20: 9214134713
Cannot parse input as integer
17 of 20: 84379811
18 of 20: 12312
19 of 20: 245
20 of 20: 13
Calculating primes...
primes: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 13, 17, 41, 71]
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Since this is a school assignment, it's probably best to avoid solving the problem and restricting ourselves to answering the concrete question. The asker will learn a lot more from solving them problem himself/herself.